# Filling an array based on other array values to the required number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to create a function say `populateAnimalArray` which takes an array as input and fills the array to the required number based on the number it takes as another argument

```
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
const animalArr = [];
populateAnimalArray(animals, 6);
// Required output: ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra', 'lion', 'tiger']
```

I have tried the following, it doesn't work on all the times.

```js
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
const animalArr = [];


function populateAnimalArray(arr, no) {
  arr.forEach(val => animalArr.push(val));
  let deficitElem; //
  if (animalArr.length < no) {
    deficitElem = no - animalArr.length;
    console.log('deficitElem', deficitElem);
    for (let i = 0; i < deficitElem; i++) {
      animalArr.push(animals[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log('animalArr', animalArr);
}

populateAnimalArray(animals, 14);
```

Comment: You are misusing map: `arr.map(val => animalArr.push(val));`  map is for returning a new array and should not have side effects, use forEach instead

Comment: @mplungjan This is a non-working invocation as it contains `undefined`. The required output shouldn't contain undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it

```js
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
let newArr = [];
function populateAnimalArray(arr, no) {
  while (arr.length<no) arr = arr.concat(animals); // add animals untile enought
  return arr.slice(0,no); // return the array sliced on passed length
}
newArr = populateAnimalArray([], 14)
console.log(newArr)
newArr = populateAnimalArray([], 3); // can handle shorter arrays too
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have overcomplicated this task. You can simply slice the array if `no` is less than `arr.length` or push using `%` (modulo) operator otherwise:

```js
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
const animalArr = [];


function populateAnimalArray(arr, no) {

 if (no < arr.length) return arr.slice(0, no);
 
 for (let i = 0; i < no; i++) {
 
  animalArr.push(arr[i % arr.length]);
 }
 
 return animalArr;
}

const res = populateAnimalArray(animals, 14);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You are overthinking it too :) See mine

Comment: @mplungjan yep, a bit, now I see ;) I didn't want to start the loop if it's not necessary and that's why I have this `if` statement

Comment: My loop does not start if it is not needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array function for this purpose.

```js
const populateAnimalArray = (arr = [], nth) => {
    let newArr = [].concat(arr);
    while (newArr.length < nth) {
        arr.forEach(item => {
            if (newArr.length >= nth) {
                return
            }
            newArr.push(item);
        })
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(populateAnimalArray(['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'], 14));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#from` to create a new array with animals.

```js
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
const populateAnimalArray = (animals, length) => {
  return Array.from({length}, (_,i) => animals[i%animals.length]);
}
console.log(populateAnimalArray(animals, 6));
console.log(populateAnimalArray(animals, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not work because with a higher no, the length of the arr is exceeding. So you can fix this by this way,

```js
const animals = ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah', 'zebra'];
const animalArr = [];

function populateAnimalArray(arr, no) {
  arr.map(val => animalArr.push(val));
  let deficitElem; //
  if (animalArr.length < no) {
    deficitElem = no - animalArr.length;
    console.log('deficitElem', deficitElem);
    let j = 0;
    while(j < deficitElem) {
      for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        animalArr.push(animals[i]);
      }
      j += animals.length;
    }
  }
  console.log('animalArr', animalArr);
}

populateAnimalArray(animals, 14);
```

Comment: Of course and not to reinvent the wheel I think that is what @Sebastian Kaczmarek has done